Add application users to DataGrid 8.4 via Secrets automagically deployed
Context
I am deploying a Spring Boot 3 application that heavily relies on the @Cacheable annotation and must use Data Grid 8.4 (Infinispan 14) as distributed cache to accommodate Spring clustering.
The installation is based on an operator that was installed by my customer's IT service.
My goal is to define a technical account to be configured both in Infinispan server and Spring Boot client in order to connect with Hot Rod client
Helm template
Exploded (don't mind plaintext passwords)
---
# Source: ipe-cache/templates/config.yaml
#Role application
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: Opaque
stringData:
  user: "application"
data:
  password: "MzRCRTRKTDVkWU91NnpIWg=="
---
# Source: ipe-cache/templates/config.yaml
# retrieve the secret data using lookup function and when not exists, return an empty dictionary / map as result
# set $jwtSecret to existing secret data or generate a random one when not exists
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  infinispan-config.yaml: |-
    infinispan:
      cacheContainer:
        caches:
          base-template:
            distributedCacheConfiguration:
              encoding:
                mediaType: application/octet-stream
              expiration:
                lifespan: "129600000"
          extended-template:
            distributedCacheConfiguration:
              configuration: base-template
              expiration:
                lifespan: "129600000"
                maxIdle: "43200000"
          ipe-template:
            distributedCacheConfiguration:
              configuration: extended-template
              encoding:
                media-type: application/octet-stream
              locking:
                striping: true
              memory:
                storage: OFF_HEAP
              mode: SYNC
              owners: 1
              statistics: true
  identities-batch.yaml: |-
    user create application -p 34BE4JL5dYOu6zHZ -g application
---
# Source: ipe-cache/templates/cache.yaml
apiVersion: infinispan.org/v2alpha1
kind: Cache
spec:
  name: "ipe.ipe-settings"
  updates:
    strategy: recreate
  clusterName: ipe-cache-infinispan
  templateName: "ipe-template"
---
# Source: ipe-cache/templates/infinispan.yaml
apiVersion: infinispan.org/v1
kind: Infinispan
spec:
  replicas: 1
  configMapName: ipe-cache-cm
  service:
    type: DataGrid
  expose:
    type: Route
    port: 11223
    targetPort: 11223
    tls:
      termination: edge
      insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Redirect
  logging:
    categories:
      org.infinispan: debug
      org.jgroups: debug
      org.jgroups.protocols.TCP: error
      org.jgroups.protocols.relay.RELAY2: error
---
# Source: ipe-cache/templates/route.yaml
kind: Route
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
spec:
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: ipe-cache-infinispan-admin
  tls:
    termination: edge
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Redirect
  port:
    targetPort: infinispan-adm
---
# Source: ipe-cache/templates/route.yaml
kind: Route
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
spec:
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: ipe-cache-infinispan
  tls:
    termination: edge
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Redirect
  port:
    targetPort: infinispan

Explained:
I deploy the Infinispan server (named ipe-cache-infinispan), along with service and route which we are not mainly interested about, and all Cache custom objects for every Infinispan cache, associated to the Infinispan node and with the proper base template. In this example I show only one cache
For the authentication, I took inspiration from an article that tells you how to auto-generate secrets.
Messing with the Infinispan documentation for Helm charts, I learn that I can use identities-batch.yaml file to configure service accounts
Problem
It doesn't work. If i retrieve the operator password from the secret that is auto-generated by Infinispan, I can access CLI and console.
But look at what happens if I log in on the CLI
[disconnected]> connect localhost:11223
Username: operator
Password: ****************
[ipe-cache-e3-dev-infinispan-0-11942@ipe-cache-e3-dev-infinispan//containers/default]> user ls
[]

On the console, instead, I can log in with operator and see all caches healthy. But application login is refused
Question(s)
What is wrong in defining the application user like that? How should I define a custom user that has at very least the application grant (in order for Hot Rod to work)?
In the meantime, how can I debug Infinispan failed logins?

It appears that you're connecting to port 11223 which is the port created for the Infinispan Operator to manage the cluster. Instead, you should connect to the endpoint exposed on port 11222.
It's possible to define multiple users for the security-realm exposed on port 11222 by providing a Secret. Please see the Infinispan Operator docs for the exact procedure: https://infinispan.org/docs/infinispan-operator/main/operator.html#adding-credentials_authn
